# Import-CSV doesn't load the file

Tags: powershell, csv, import

```
    $ConversoinTable = Import-CSV -path '.\Conversion.csv'
    $ConversionTable
```

I already created the file called Conversion.csv and it has contents in it. When I try to import it, it doesn't give me any error but also doesn't display anything.

I'm new to the powershell. I don't think the way that I import the CSV file and save to a variable is wrong but am not sure.

Comment: What error do you get if you do `Import-CSV -path '.\Conversion.csv'` without putting it into a variable?

Comment: ".\" is probably accessing the wrong folder.

Comment: Your variables are named differently $ConversoinTable and $ConversionTable